# Cant find the pip.exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So i installed both version 3.7.6 and 3.8.3 and i was trying to fix the "pip is not recognized" problem through YouTube,google etc.. but they all have the same similar step and it is to find the "pip.exe" file and add it to the system  yet i don't have a "pip.exe" file nor do i have a "Scripts" file i searched in the easy access (because that's where i find anything there) but i seemed to have no luck i also searched through the Python files but no luck whatsoever, am i doing something wrong?...maybe i installed a "wrong version" or something

Comment: Check "Install pip" upon installing

Comment: Does `python -m pip` work though? You don't necessarily need pip.exe to use Pip.

Answer (score 0):

Upon installation of Python, the PATH environment variable is updated to point to the directory where Python is installed.

1) Check PATH, if there exists no entry for Python, add the address pointing to your `python.exe`(Default path for Py3.7 is `C:\Program Files\Python37` and for Py3.8 is `C:\Program Files\Python38`).

2) Better yet just reinstall both of them, also please check the box which asks you to `Disable the max PATH length` and also the `add to PATH` checkbox.